# Cannot get delegate to work between my views

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I need to call some methods from one view to another, and I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my **ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mySettings.h"

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) getDefaults;
- (void) updateSubTotal: ( float ) value;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id delegate;
.
. (other declarations)
.
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "mySettings.h"

@interface ViewController  (  ) 
@property (assign) mySettings *settingsVC;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-  ( void ) viewDidLoad {
    [ super viewDidLoad ] ;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.userDefaults =  [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.Just-The-Tip"] ;
    [ self getDefaults ] ;

    self.arrPercent = @ [ @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25",@"26",@"27",@"28",@"29",@"30",@"31",@"32",@"33",@"34",@"35",@"36",@"37",@"38",@"39",@"40",@"41",@"42",@"43",@"44",@"45",@"46",@"47",@"48",@"49",@"50" ] ;
    self.arrPeople = @ [ @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20" ] ;

    self.myPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.myPicker.delegate = self;

    if ( self.bRememberLastBill )
    {
        self.subtotal =  [ self.userDefaults floatForKey:@"sub_total" ] ;
        self.strSubTotal =  [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", self.subtotal ] ;
        [ self updateSubTotal:-3 ] ;
    }

    // BEGIN ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD
    UIToolbar * keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 32)];;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(clearClicked:)],
                                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)], nil
                                    ];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
    self.field_SubTotal.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
    // END ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 60)];
    self.field_SubTotal.rightView = paddingView;
    self.field_SubTotal.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    self.settingsVC = [[mySettings alloc] init];
    self.settingsVC.delegate = self ;

    [ self animate ] ;
}

-  ( void ) getDefaults
{
    // lots of stuff here
}

-  ( void ) updateSubTotal: ( float ) value
{
    // even more code here
}
```

**mySettings.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface mySettings : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
.
. (a bunch of declarations)
.
@end
```

**mySettings.m**

```
#import "mySettings.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface mySettings  (  ) 

@end

@implementation mySettings

@synthesize delegate;

-  ( void ) viewDidLoad {
     [ super viewDidLoad ] ;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //self.userDefaults =  [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] ;
    self.userDefaults =  [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.Just-The-Tip"] ;

    [ self getDefaults ] ;

    self.textDefaultTax.text =  [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", self.default_tax ] ;
    self.textDefaultTip.text =  [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", self.default_tip ] ;

    // BEGIN ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD
    UIToolbar * keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                      [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)],
                                      nil]];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
    self.textDefaultTip.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
    self.textDefaultTax.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
    // END ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD

    [ self animate ] ;
}

// a few methods later

- (IBAction)up_default_exclude_tax:(id)sender {
    self.bExcludeTax = self.switchExcludeTax.isOn;
    [ self setDefaults ] ;
    [ self.delegate getDefaults ];
    [ self.delegate updateSubTotal:-3 ];
}
```

Comment: So what methods from which views aren't calling?

Comment: @rocky I tried to call both the getDefaults and the updateSubTotal methods but none of them works. I made some breakpoints and it never gets there.

Comment: Is mySettings supposed to be ViewControllerDelegate?

Comment: Where did you try to call the getDefaults and the updateSubTotal? There are some line `[ self getDefaults ] ;`

Comment: What is `self.delegate` when `- (IBAction)up_default_exclude_tax:(id)sender` is called ?

Comment: So does ViewController call mySettings?  Or reverse?  Usually a delegate is used to send data backward to a previous view controller or used when creating NSObjects that could act as managers.

Comment: And I don't see where  -(void)getUserDefaults{} or - (void) updateSubTotal: ( float ) value; is located.

Comment: @DrRocker mySettings is the one calling the methods in ViewController.

Comment: I've just edited my question with even more code. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, you have almost confused me :). The way you are implementing delegate design pattern and connecting view controllers is not the suggested/documented way of doing it.

Lets proceed step by step.

Step 1: MySettings (like UITableViewController) implements some feature and relies on its delegate to implement others.

So, following points to take away from here:

1. protocol definition must be `MySettingsDelegate` and not `ViewControllerDelegate`.
2. rename `mySettings` to `MySettingsViewController`.
3. `MySettingsViewController` should not import `ViewController`. It must use its `delegate` property to interact with `ViewController`.

This is how my `MySettingsViewController` would look like post these changes.

**MySettingsViewController.h**

`

```
@protocol MySettingsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) getDefaults;
- (void) updateSubTotal: ( float ) value;
@end




@interface MySettingsViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
.
. (a bunch of declarations)
.
@end`
```

Step2: You don't need to call @synthesis on properties any more. Also, before calling a method on delegate it is always good practice to do a nil check. Please see how my `MySettingsViewController.m` would look like. I have also added some NSLog statement for you to verify if controls comes there or not.

**MySettingsViewController.m**

```
@implementation MySettingsViewController
-  ( void ) viewDidLoad {
    [ super viewDidLoad ] ;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //self.userDefaults =  [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] ;
    self.userDefaults =  [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.Just-The-Tip"] ;

    [ self getDefaults ] ;

    self.textDefaultTax.text =  [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", self.default_tax ] ;
    self.textDefaultTip.text =  [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", self.default_tip ] ;

    // BEGIN ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD
    UIToolbar * keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                      [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)],
                                      nil]];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
    self.textDefaultTip.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
    self.textDefaultTax.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
    // END ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD

    [ self animate ] ;
}

// a few methods later

- (IBAction)up_default_exclude_tax:(id)sender {
    self.bExcludeTax = self.switchExcludeTax.isOn;
    [self setDefaults];

    NSLog(@"Action taken");

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getDefaults)]) {
        NSLog(@"Calling getDefaults");
        [self.delegate getDefaults];
    }

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(updateSubTotal:)]) {
        NSLog(@"Calling updateSubTotal:");
        [self.delegate updateSubTotal:-3];
    }
}
```

Step 3: Now, that my support class ready, lets use it. Time to write ViewController class. Not sure why you added delegate in header of ViewController as well, we literally do not need it here. This is how my `ViewController.h` will look like:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, MySettingsViewControllerDelegate> {

}

.
. (other declarations)
.
@end
```

Steps 4: Now comes the main part. Please ensure you hold a strong reference to `MySettingsViewController`. This is how my `ViewController.m` would look like:

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MySettingsViewController *settingsVC;
@end
-  ( void ) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad ] ;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.userDefaults =  [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.Just-The-Tip"] ;
    [ self getDefaults ] ;

    self.arrPercent = @ [ @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25",@"26",@"27",@"28",@"29",@"30",@"31",@"32",@"33",@"34",@"35",@"36",@"37",@"38",@"39",@"40",@"41",@"42",@"43",@"44",@"45",@"46",@"47",@"48",@"49",@"50" ] ;
    self.arrPeople = @ [ @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20" ] ;

    self.myPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.myPicker.delegate = self;

    if ( self.bRememberLastBill )
    {
        self.subtotal =  [ self.userDefaults floatForKey:@"sub_total" ] ;
        self.strSubTotal =  [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", self.subtotal ] ;
        [ self updateSubTotal:-3 ] ;
    }

    // BEGIN ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD
    UIToolbar * keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 32)];;
    keyboardDoneButtonView.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(clearClicked:)],
                                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)], nil
                                    ];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
    self.field_SubTotal.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
    // END ENABLE DONE BUTTON FOR NUMPAD

    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 60)];
    self.field_SubTotal.rightView = paddingView;
    self.field_SubTotal.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    self.settingsVC = [[MySettingsViewController alloc] init];
    self.settingsVC.delegate = self ;

    [ self animate ] ;
}

-  ( void ) getDefaults
{
    // lots of stuff here
}

-  ( void ) updateSubTotal: ( float ) value
{
    // even more code here
}
```

I believe this must solve your issue and would bring clarity to delegate pattern. You also need to ensure that while `MySettingsViewController` is active and calls its delegate, `ViewController` also stays in memory.

**Edit: If you are using storyboard**

Please ensure you are setting the delegate correctly on the right object. Do not instantiate your own object.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueRegistrationUserAction"]) {
        [(MySettingsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

**Final Edit (Fixed in Code):**

So, I took a look at your code and found the issue. It was apparently different objects issue. You are using storyboard and also creating a `mySettings` object in code as well. When you connect via storyboard, you should use the object created from storyboard and avoid creating your own. When I changed the below method in your `ViewController.m`, it fixed the issue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.settingsVC = (mySettings *)segue.destinationViewController;
    self.settingsVC.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: This was my first time implementing delegate pattern, so I knew I must've had it backwards somehow. Thank you for pointing it out, and telling me straight in my face (not being sarcastic at all). I'll try fixing my code tonight and report back with results.

Comment: No problem :). Would be glad if this resolves your issue! Let me know if you  need any help in this regard.

Comment: So I've updated my code to having everything you mentioned, including the segue stuff - assuming it's in ViewController.h - no dice. For some reason, when I put a break below your "Action Taken" log line, my _delegate value is always null. Am I doing something wrong? ----- My entire code repo is here https://github.com/tambnguyen/Just-The-Tip/tree/master/Just%20The%20Tip, would you mind take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to send data from your ViewController to your Settings via the delegate pattern.In your Settings.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SettingsDelegate
@required
- (void) getDefaults;
- (void) updateSubTotal: ( float ) value;
@end

@interface Settings : UIViewController 

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Then in your ViewController.h

```
#import "Settings.h"

@interface Settings : UIViewController<ViewControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@end
```

This basically says that your ViewController is going to contain the delegate methods that you defined in the SettingsDelegate protocol.

So in your ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void) viewDidLoad{
   viewController.delegate = self; //somehow get a copy of your viewController instance and set the delegate. This doesn't have to be in viewDidLoad, but it needs to happen sometime.
}
- (void) getDefaults{
    //Do stuff. You probably want to change the return type to something other than void if we are actually getting defaults here.
}
- (void) updateSubTotal: ( float ) value{
    //Do stuff.
}
...
@end
```

Then in your Settings.m, when the appropriate time comes. you can call:

```
[self.delegate getDefaults];
```

Comment: Thank you! I will fix my code tonight and report back :)

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't what I was after. I need to be able to call getDefaults and updateSubTotal of ViewController from mySettings.

Comment: Then just swap the names of the view controllers. I'll update my answer.