# Delegates method never being called

Tags: ios, delegates

I am quite new to IOS, and I was working with delegates to call a method in parent ViewController.

**ViewControllerRegistration.h**

```
@protocol RegistrationViewControllerDelegate;
@interface ViewControllerRegistration : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<RegistrationViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)registerNewUser:(id)sender;
@end

// 3. Definition of the delegate's interface
@protocol RegistrationViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)loginResult:(NSString*)loginData;
@end
```

**ViewControllerRegistration.m**

```
- (void)registerNewUser:(id)sender {
 id<RegistrationViewControllerDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;

    // Our delegate method is optional, so we should
    // check that the delegate implements it
    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loginResult:)]) {
        [strongDelegate loginResult: @"@WHY YOU NOT BEING CALLED?"];
    }
```

Parents:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "ViewControllerRegistration.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GPPSignInDelegate,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate,RegistrationViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize signInButton;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

ViewControllerRegistration  *detailViewController = [[ViewControllerRegistration alloc] init];
    // Assign self as the delegate for the child view controller
    detailViewController.delegate = self;
}
//Local Strategy
- (IBAction)navigateToLocalSignUpNavBtn:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueRegisterUserAction" sender:self];
}

// Implement the delegate methods for RegistrationViewControllerDelegate
-(void)loginResult:(NSString*)loginData{
    NSLog(@"I am called");
    //^Above is never printed. That means delegate method is never called
}
```

Please note, my parent view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

The delegate method is never called. Tried debugging, but in vain.

Comment: The problem here is that `detailViewController` you are instantiating is not the same that you will get after `performSegueWithIdentifier`. So for the current visible `ViewControllerRegistration` delegate will be nil. Try to use 
`- prepareForSegue:sender:` and get `destinationController` to set delegate property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view controller you are creating in `viewDidLoad` isn't the same one that you will be segueing to. It's another instance that will be deallocated at the end of the method.  You need to access the correct instance in `prepareForSegue` and set the delegate there.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueRegistrationUserAction"]) {
        [(ViewControllerRegistration *)segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Bingo. :)  Spot on, man!!! Spent several crazy hours, digging in. I knew that there is some problem with references and it might be getting deallocated. Thought declaring @strong references will do the trick, that was n't the case. Know my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, I had explained this in length on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467416/cannot-get-delegate-to-work-between-my-views/32569328#32569328). Please take a look and let me know if you have any specific question post that. I hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate. Went through the post and really did n't find any differences. I followed the same pattern. Just changed the part where I need to hold a strong reference to ViewControllerRegistration. 

`@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewControllerRegistration *settingsVC;
    self.settingsVC = [[ViewControllerRegistration alloc] init];
    // Assign self as the delegate for child controller
    self.settingsVC.delegate = self;`
But in vain. :(

Comment: Can you please put a breakpoint in your `registerNewUser:` method and tell me what is the value of `self.delegate`

Comment: Also, since you are using story board, I believe you are setting delegate on correct `ViewControllerRegistration ` object. Can you please double check that.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for steering. I was atleast able to find my mistake reading your post, but didn't know  where to set the delegate correctly for the view that i will be segueing . @Dan answer cleared my confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. That story board stuff totally stumped me. I've also updated my yesterday's post to add this angle. Glad your issue is resolved. Cheers :)!